# Get angle from any point

Tags: trigonometry

**How can I get an angle of a point positive or negative? When I use tangent the angle only appears in the first two quadrants.**

[image]

**So I need to do some magic and make it so that I can get the angle of any point on a two dimensional plane.
So for example, (-10 ~ x, -10 ~ y) must be 225 degrees, or 5/4 rads.**

Hope no one rates this as nonconstructive, have been trying to figure this out for over an hour.

Comment: You mean 225 degrees?

Comment: Yea, fixed it already.

Comment: Can I get the arcCos of the X and the arcSin of the Y, and combine them somehow to make the angle I need..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want different values for $\frac{x}{y}$ and $\frac{-x}{-y}$, your function will have to take both $x$ and $y$ as input.

If this is for programming, you may want to look into functions called [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

If you just want an algebraic formula, you can use:
$$f(x,y) = 2 \arctan \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} + x}$$

This will fail when $y = 0, x < 0$, but if you interpret $\arctan \frac{\pm 1}{0}$ to be $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$, then it still works out.

Comment: Yes, this is for programming. I use .Net framework's Math.Atan2, but it always returned in the first and fourth quadrant. Maybe I'll implement my own function. Be back, see how that goes.

Comment: You may want to use $2 \arctan \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - x}{y}$ then. Using more operations in the denominator tends to yield less precision.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the angle, without being given a certain domain, just from the tangent of the angle. First, you must be given the domain of the angle, $\theta$. Then, you may need to know something else. I should elaborate.

Say, we want to find $ \theta $ such that $ \tan \theta = 1 $ and $ 0 \le x \le 2 \pi $. We know that $ \theta $ must be an odd multiple of $45^\circ$ and we know that $ \theta $ is positive in the first and third quadrants. So, $\theta$ must be $ 45^\circ $ or $ 225^\circ $. Now, if you are given the sign of $ \sin \theta $ as positive, you know that $ \theta = 45^\circ $, since $ \sin (45^\circ) > 0 $ but $ \sin (225^\circ) < 0 $. If you were not given this extra piece of information, there would not have been a unique solution.

So there may be an ambiguity if all you are given is a domain.